# Vuetify rail, v-list-item, text centered below an icon

Tags: vuetifyjs3

I'm in the process of migrating from Vuetify 2 to Vuetify 3 (or is it a redesign).
Struggling big time.

How can I get the item.text centered below an item.icon?
See below:

```
    <v-navigation-drawer
      clipped
      rail
      rail-width="110"
      permanent="true"
    >
    <!-- left items -->
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
          router
          exact
          active-class="highlighted"
          :class="item.path === $route.path ? 'highlighted' : ''"
        >
            <v-list-item-content >
                <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.title" class="center"/>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main>
      <v-container class="pl-8 ml-0" fluid>
        <Nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text-center` class:

```html
<v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.title" class="text-center"/>
```

Btw. I don't think `v-list-item-content` exists anymore. You can just use a div instead or remove it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the v-list-item-content and changed into a div. The icon I did no set with :prepend-icon="item.icon". Unluckily still not back to my original design

[image]

I end up with this:

[image]

(edited)
Finally after another attempt:

```
    <v-navigation-drawer
      rail
      rail-width="110"
      permanent="true"
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item 
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :to="item.to"
          router
          exact
          selected-class="highlighted"
          class="text-center"
          height="64"
          >
          <v-icon :icon="item.icon" class="mb-1" color="grey-darken-2" /> 
          <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.title"/>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```